# What data structure does Python have to associate two arrays?

Tags: python, data-structures

Is there a data structure in Python to associate two arrays in Python so that if the user inputs one of the values in the first array, a random value from the second array is returned?

To illustrate this with an example let's consider a chatbot that may get different queries from the user from a list of possibilities such as:

```
['hi', 'hello'] ​
```

and the bot replies with a random answer from another list of words:

```
['hi there', 'hey you']
```

How do I return a random word from the second list if the query matches the first list? Please note that there might be different pairs of lists, so I was thinking of having a dictionary in the form of `d = {tuple : tuple}`, but I don't think that would be the best structure for this scenario since that type of dictionary is meant to be used as d[tuple] to access values, but in my case I only want to check one item of that tuple.

Edit: Please note there will be multiple pairs of arrays, not just one pair. To explain it in one model (taken from user @lllrnr101) it would be:

```
P1(list_of_promts)->A1(list_of_answers_only_if_match_in_P1); 
P2(list_of_promts)->A2(list_of_answers_only_if_match_in_P2);
```

Comment: set()? prompts  = {'hi', 'hello'} ; if user_input in my_prompts: return random.choice(answers)

Comment: Alternatively, `l = ['hi there', 'hey you']` and `d = {'hi': l, 'hello': l}`. As in the list of replies is assigned to each word.

Comment: @Peter that looks repetitive having to type in the `l` variable for every key of `d`.

Comment: @lllrnr101 your solution works only with one set that is querying and selecting from the same set.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have multiple question_promts? and mulitple answer promtts?

Comment: @lllrnr101 yes.

Comment: P1(list_of_promts)->A1(list_of_answers_only_if_match_in_P1);  P2(list_of_promts)->A2(list_of_answers_only_if_match_in_P2);  .... you have model like this?

Comment: @lllrnr101 exactly. Thanks for the formula representation!

Comment: @multigoodverse I was just suggesting a potential way of handling it, not the best way of actually generating the dict. A quicker way to not type each word for example would be `{word: l for word in ('hi there', 'hey you')}`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better that you extract all of your prompt lists to one. Because for one input, you have to look through all of prompt lists, which makes the code O(n^2); but having them all in a dictionary, and index of their corresponding answer list with them, will make it doable in O(n). And with one `for` loop you can answer to all of the inputs.

```
import random

inputs = ['hi', 'bye']
prompts = {'hi': 0, 'hello': 0, 'goodbye': 1, 'bye': 1}
answers = (['hi there', 'hey you'], ['bye bye!', 'goodbye'])

for i in inputs:
    if i in prompts:
        print(random.choice(answers[prompts[i]]))
```

Here if an input exists, a random answer from the appropriate list in the answers will be printed.

Comment: That's not ideal because there will be multiple pairs of arrays. In your answer you are only considering one pair.

Comment: you mean like multiple input lists with their corresponding answer lists?

Comment: Exactly! I made some edits to explain it better.

Comment: @multigoodverse I made some edits. Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use lists to put your question & answer sets.
You can not do in less than O(n) (n being the number of groups you have
) because you will have to check each question set.

Something like below:

```
>>> questions_1 = {'hi', 'hello', 'hey there'}
>>> answers_1 = {'hey!!!', 'wazaaa!!', 'whats up!'}
>>> 
>>> questions_2 = {'name', 'whats your name', 'other variant'}
>>> answers_2 = {'bot', 'your bot'}
>>> 
>>> questions = [questions_1, questions_2]
>>> answers = [answers_1, answers_2]
```

Then loop over them to find the answer:

```
>>> for i, question_set in enumerate(questions): # or use zip(questions, answers)
...     if user_input in question_set:
...             return random.choice(answers[i])
```

Alternatively (not recommended), sacrifice space and use a map of (ugly) form {q11->a1, q21->a1, q21->a2, q22->a2}